# understand models relationship . Its python, Django my q is ideologic

Tags: django, python-2.7, web, relationship, models

Im developing CRM system in which i have 2 models

**Order**

---

```
items_in_order=models.ManyToManyField(Item)
```

**Item**

---

```
name=models.Charfield()
price=models.DecimalField()
```

---

As you can see Orderlist can have multiple items in it.

I want to have order list in which i can add an items with quantity.

For example:
ORDER

yellow flower (5$) | 10 pcs
blue flower (3$) | 3pcs

For now i can only add these two flowers to order, without quantity.
How these can be implemented ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `through` model that you get while using `ManyToMany` fields

```
class Order(models.Model):
    items_in_order=models.ManyToManyField('Item', through='Quantity')

class Item(models.Mode):
    name=models.Charfield()
    price=models.DecimalField()

class Quantity(models.Model):
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    order = models.ForeignKey('Order')
    item = models.ForeignKey('Item')
```

Documentation on [extra fields on `ManyToMany`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships)